# Unable to connect Pod using minikube IP and NodePort

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, minikube, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have to communicate with the same POD in minikube using the minikubeip and nodeport.

Operating System : **Ubuntu 18.0 5**
Minikube Version :  **v1.13.1**

**Problem here is:**  when ever i try to connect to the same pod by using the Minikube ip and the nodeport assigned i get an socket exception .

**`Explanation of the problem`**

This image show that the pod is up and running
[pod is up and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvgI1.jpg)

This image shows that the service for the respective pod is up and some of the ports for that pod are exposed using the node port
[Service for the above pod is up and respective port numbers are assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM9mW.jpg)

This image shows the ip of the minikube
[Minikube ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdqLX.jpg)

**Here the main issue starts .**
Here i have logged into the pod using the **kubectl exec** command  and try runnig the ***nmap***  command it shows that all the ports are opened **but for the port number **31900** it shows the state as filtered** . As the state of the port is filtered i m not able to communicate to the same pod using the node port assigned to the pod .
[Namp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlNRa.jpg)

**Same goes with the telnet whenever i do telnet to the minikube ip and port number 31900 it is not able to connect**  it just says  trying
[telnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmHAk.jpg)

when i run the complete application it says socket exception as it is not able to connect to the minikube ip and port number assigned .

Thanks for your help

Comment: Add Pod's YAML, service's YAML, and the exact error message you faced to question-body.

Comment: `Unable to connect Pod using the same pod`- doesn't make any sense.